In-app Purchases and Subscriptions section missing on app store connect
I've had a subscription approved for being used with my app, however when i want to add this subscription to the new version im uploading, the entire 'in-app purchases and subscriptions' group section is missing so i can't add anything.
I have previously had this section showing prior to the subscription approved and was attaching the subscription to the build but had to remove it at the time. Since then the subscription was approved, but now it won't show at all.
Everything else is set up fine in terms of accepting documents, including meta data etc.
I've read some other posts on here with the same problem, but none of the answers help with this.
Has anyone experienced this before?


If it's your first time submitting a subscription through app store connect, you need to have your subscription in 'submit for review' status, alongside your current app version, and this will get the 'In-app purchases and subscriptions' section to appear when submitting a new build.
This is a bit of a odd process, given the subscription was already approved and ready to go, however after speaking with an Apple advisor they mentioned they have a unique process if it's your first time, and hence i've had to completely remove the sub, then re-make it and submit it alongside my app version.
